# Could not load file or assembly 'EntitySpaces.SQLiteProvider' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sqlite, .net-assembly, entityspaces

Could not load file or assembly 'EntitySpaces.SQLiteProvider' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is solved , BEcause we change the entityspaces to entity framework and acccess database through models
now solved